# Storing All Worksheets Of A Workbook In An Array [Run-time error 438]

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to have VBA use a filebrowser to get a different Excel file and store its Sheet-names in an Array "sheetNames".
It seems like the filebrowser and opening the FormatImport Sub works well, but there is a Problem with the For Each loop. When I hover over the variable ws it says "ws = Nothing".  Pls ignore my taskbar  <3

[error message - object doesnt support property or method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fmZaa.jpg)

[The problematic code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40Ype.jpg)

[Where the problematic code is called](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2dnbS.png)

```
Public Sub FormatImport(ByVal OpenBook As Workbook)

  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Dim i As Integer
  Dim sheetNames() As Variant
  Dim strg As String

  strg = OpenBook.Name
  Debug.Print strg
  i = 0
  For Each ws In OpenBook
    sheetNames(i) = ws.Name
    i = i + 1
    
  Next ws    
  End Sub


Private Sub GetImport()

Dim FileToOpen As Variant
Dim OpenBook As Workbook

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Browse for File")
If FileToOpen <> False Then
    Set OpenBook = Application.Workbooks.Open(FileToOpen)

    Call FormatImport(OpenBook)
    OpenBook.Close True
End If

End Sub
```

Could it have something to do with the other Excel file actually opening ?
I also tried an example from here:   https://www.automateexcel.com/vba/list-all-sheets-in-workbook/

Comment: Need to be `For Each ws In OpenBook.Worksheets`. But the next row will also fail as you can't assign a value to an array without having it either declares as static array `Dim array(1 to 10)` or by using `Redim` (eg `Redim sheetNames(1 to OpenBook.Worksheets.Count`)

Comment: @FunThomas  Thank you so so so much, it worked like a charm!! <3
I am just wondering why you'd want the array to start at 1 instead of the typical 0 but it works either way!  Again thank you so much for your time, you've made my day and I am not even kidding!  C:

Comment: I want to start at 1 because `Worksheets` is a VBA `Collection` and those start at index 1 also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already more or less answered in the comment:

**(a)** You need to use the `Worksheets` property of the workbook: (`For Each ws in OpenBook.Worksheets`).

**(b)** You will need to define the array so that it has enough members. `Dim sheetNames() As Variant` will only declare a variable but creates no members, so `sheetNames(i)` will throw an Runtime error 9 ("*subscript out of range*"). If you don't know the size at compile time and declare the array like you did, you will need to issue a `Redim`-statement. It's a matter of taste if you make it 0 or 1-based.

**(c)** Not sure if you really need that array. I image that you later accesses the worksheets via that sheetName-Array, eg `OpenBook.Worksheets(sheetNames(1))`, but you can also access them directly via index like `OpenBook.Worksheets(1)`